# Is there in React something like 'local' component Context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-context

I have a set of complex components with many inner parts in some array. On Click I need to create new one and to set in the array. But to deal with its complexity, the single complex component, I wanted to create for each its own 'Context' on the component creation or something similar to deal with its local property drill problems. I don't need redux because it global for all the components.

Comment: if you need it locally, that is the perfect use case for `state`

Comment: Is it single solution? Because I need to set all as props and as result I get property drill if component is complex by itself.

Comment: Technically you can use redux even if your entire app is only having single component. But yes, whenever you only need it locally instead of global, use `state`. You can either have `useState` or `useReducer`

Comment: Prop drilling means passing the same props from component to child component to child component to child component, if that's the case, you should use react context or redux to solve that problem

Comment: I think it would be useful if it was something like 'local' Context/Redux.

Comment: Yes. But I need something global but locally.

Comment: That sounds like you just want React's native Context...

Answer (score 0):

Let me put it in answer to point out couple of potential misconception which you might have.

You mentioned about `local property drill problems`

Below is the explanation of what `prop drilling` is, there is no such thing as `local prop drill`. Whenever you mention that you have `prop drill` problem, you will usually have many components involved

> Prop drilling is the process in a React app where props are passed from one part of a tree to another by going through other parts that do not need the data, but only help in passing it through the tree

Second misconception which you might have

> I don't need redux because it global for all the components.

Yes, `Redux` or `React Context` is available globally for all the components, but they are not accessible to `redux` by default. All the components do not have default access to `redux store` by default, in order to access the store, you will need `connect` or some hooks to access the store.

From the above two misconceptions, I hope you understand the problem that you are trying to solve

Comment: React context is available to the child components of whatever has the provider. It's not necessarily global in no way.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But imagine you deal with many similar components with deeply nested structure. It hard to works with when no any property drill solutions. And what if I create the component on every click.

Comment: So I need hook useLocalContext() that created automatically when the component created. The component is sub-tree, and for all the components exists its own context  because the component so nested and so complex. Or I something don't understand right or I create very complex components...

Comment: So I understand it right - React can't effectively solve the problem?

Comment: @AKX: exactly my point when i mentioned about `but they are not accessible by default`

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution. So when I create component with very nested structure I need just one global Context or Redux. In Redux/Context I store array/set of models/object of the complex component, not component itself. When I create the new complex component at the same moment we create the model of the complex component with its id. And each this complex component get reach its model by the id. It global, but we find a model by id, so its at the same time something local. Something like that...